# ORM: Updating all models of a given instance

Tags: javascript, orm, sequelize.js

I'm having an conceptual issue on how to update all instances of a model once I have updated it.

Imagine the following method `renameUser` (could be any ORM):

```js
async function renameUser(userId: number, newUsername: string) {
  const user = await User.findByPk(userId);
  await user.update({ username: newUsername });
}
```

And the following usage:

```js
const user = await User.create({ username: "old" });
// user.username === "old"

this.renameUser(user.id, "new");

// still, user.username === "old"
```

Obviously this problem wouldn't exist if I would pass the `user` object directly into the update method, but that only works in this simple example - In my case it is actually not possible to share the same instance, since it can be modified via hooks in an entirely different context.

So, one simple solution would be to call `user.reload()` after the call, which will pull the latest user data from the database:

```js
const user = await User.create({ username: "old" });
// user.username === "old"

this.renameUser(user.id, "new");

user.reload();
// now: user.username === "new"
```

However, this requires me to know that the `renameUser` method will change my user object. In this case it is obvious, but if the method is called that's not always possible.

**Is there any pattern I can use to work around this?** One thing which came in my mind was to create a `UserFactory` which ensures that I only have one instance of a user (indexed by its primary key) at any time, and then update that instance. But I was wondering how others solve it? Is it a common problem?

Answer (score 1):

Why you dont use `.save()` in `updateUser` function?

```
const renameUser = async (userId, newUsername) => {
  const user = await User.findByPk(userId);

  user.username = newUsername;
  await user.save();

  return user;
}
```

and use it like this

```
const user = await User.create({ username: "old" });
// user.username === "old"

user = await this.renameUser(user.id, "new");

// now, user.username === "new"
```

Comment: See my question: "Obviously this problem wouldn't exist if I would pass the user object directly into the update method, but that only works in this simple example - In my case it is actually not possible to share the same instance, since it can be modified via hooks in an entirely different context."

Answer (score 0):

You can run your queries more efficiently by just running an update [using the `Model.update()` function](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-update) instead of [querying for an Instance and then updating it](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-instances.html#updating-an-instance).

```js
async function renameUser(userId: number, newUsername: string) {
  
  const [ updatedRowCount, updateRowOnPostgresOnly ] = await User.update({
    username: newUsername,
  }, {
    where: {
      id: userId,
    },
  });
  // you can use the updated row count to see if the user changed.
  const isUpdated = updatedRowCount > 0;
  return isUpdated;
}
```

Now you can await the result to see if the row changed, even without loading it.

```js
const user = await User.create({ username: "old" });
// user.username === "old"

const isUpdated = await this.renameUser(user.id, "new");

if (isUpdated) {
  user.reload();
  // now: user.username === "new"
}
```

> *Note that in your example you are not using `await` on the `async runameUser()` function.*

This varies from your question a bit, but if you are already working with Model instances then you can use `Instance.changed()` to get the changed fields.

```
const user = await User.create({ username: "old" });
user.username = "old";
const changed = user.changed(); // == [ "username" ]
if (changed.length) {
  await user.save();
}
```

> *Note that in that example it checks for `changed.length` but really Sequelize won't do anything if you `await instance.save()` and nothing is in `instance.changed()` - [change awareness of save](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-instances.html#change-awareness-of-save).